# How to issue Apache Phoenix sqlline.py query with filter on UUID?

Tags: hbase, uuid, apache-phoenix

I'm working on a more complex query, but have my problem reduced to something simple. I'm hoping someone can help me with.

Given the following tables (see *HOSTED_APPS_METADATA_UUID* below )

```
 !tables
+------------+--------------+-------------------------------+---------------+----------+------------+----------------------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------+
| TABLE_CAT  | TABLE_SCHEM  |          TABLE_NAME           |  TABLE_TYPE   | REMARKS  | TYPE_NAME  | SELF_REFERENCING_COL_NAME  | REF_GENERATION  | INDEX_STATE  | IMMUTABLE_ROWS  | SALT_BUCKETS  | MULTI_TEN |
+------------+--------------+-------------------------------+---------------+----------+------------+----------------------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------+
|            | SYSTEM       | CATALOG                       | SYSTEM TABLE  |          |            |                            |                 |              | false           | null          | false     |
|            | SYSTEM       | FUNCTION                      | SYSTEM TABLE  |          |            |                            |                 |              | false           | null          | false     |
|            | SYSTEM       | LOG                           | SYSTEM TABLE  |          |            |                            |                 |              | true            | 32            | false     |
|            | SYSTEM       | SEQUENCE                      | SYSTEM TABLE  |          |            |                            |                 |              | false           | 2             | false     |
|            | SYSTEM       | STATS                         | SYSTEM TABLE  |          |            |                            |                 |              | false           | null          | false     |
|            |              | CONTAINER_METRICS             | TABLE         |          |            |                            |                 |              | true            | null          | false     |
|            |              | HOSTED_APPS_METADATA_UUID     | TABLE         |          |            |                            |                 |              | false           | null          | false     |
|            |              | INSTANCE_HOST_METADATA        | TABLE         |          |            |                            |                 |              | false           | null          | false     |
|            |              | METRICS_METADATA_UUID         | TABLE         |          |            |                            |                 |              | false           | null          | false     |
|            |              | METRIC_AGGREGATE_DAILY_UUID   | TABLE         |          |            |                            |                 |              | true            | null          | false     |
|            |              | METRIC_AGGREGATE_HOURLY_UUID  | TABLE         |          |            |                            |                 |              | true            | null          | false     |
|            |              | METRIC_AGGREGATE_MINUTE_UUID  | TABLE         |          |            |                            |                 |              | true            | null          | false     |
|            |              | METRIC_AGGREGATE_UUID         | TABLE         |          |            |                            |                 |              | true            | null          | false     |
|            |              | METRIC_RECORD_DAILY_UUID      | TABLE         |          |            |                            |                 |              | true            | null          | false     |
|            |              | METRIC_RECORD_HOURLY_UUID     | TABLE         |          |            |                            |                 |              | true            | null          | false     |
|            |              | METRIC_RECORD_MINUTE_UUID     | TABLE         |          |            |                            |                 |              | true            | null          | false     |
|            |              | METRIC_RECORD_UUID            | TABLE         |          |            |                            |                 |              | true            | null          | false     |
|            |              | METRIC_TRANSIENT              | TABLE         |          |            |                            |                 |              | true            | null          | false     |
+------------+--------------+-------------------------------+---------------+----------+------------+----------------------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------+
!describe HOSTED_APPS_METADATA_UUID
+------------+--------------+----------------------------+--------------+------------+------------+--------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+----------+-------------+----+
| TABLE_CAT  | TABLE_SCHEM  |         TABLE_NAME         | COLUMN_NAME  | DATA_TYPE  | TYPE_NAME  | COLUMN_SIZE  | BUFFER_LENGTH  | DECIMAL_DIGITS  | NUM_PREC_RADIX  | NULLABLE  | REMARKS  | COLUMN_DEF  | SQ |
+------------+--------------+----------------------------+--------------+------------+------------+--------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+----------+-------------+----+
|            |              | HOSTED_APPS_METADATA_UUID  | HOSTNAME     | 12         | VARCHAR    | null         | null           | null            | null            | 0         |          |             | nu |
|            |              | HOSTED_APPS_METADATA_UUID  | UUID         | -2         | BINARY     | 4            | null           | null            | null            | 1         |          |             | nu |
|            |              | HOSTED_APPS_METADATA_UUID  | APP_IDS      | 12         | VARCHAR    | null         | null           | null            | null            | 1         |          |             | nu |
+------------+--------------+----------------------------+--------------+------------+------------+--------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+----------+-------------+----+

There is a column called UUID of BINARY type.

I'm using sqlline.py to issue a query. Here's a simple one:

select * from HOSTED_APPS_METADATA_UUID;
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                            HOSTNAME                             |     UUID     |                                                          APP_IDS                                                           |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| hn0-gjshdi.5uu4vnfquqlelgdmoqysq1y3jg.cx.internal.cloudapp.net  | [B@66e8997c  | hiveserver2,hivemetastore,resourcemanager,historyserver,HOST,applicationhistoryserver,jobhistoryserver,namenode,ams-hbase  |
| hn1-gjshdi.5uu4vnfquqlelgdmoqysq1y3jg.cx.internal.cloudapp.net  | [B@6f0cb5a1  | hiveserver2,hivemetastore,resourcemanager,historyserver,HOST,namenode                                                      |
| wn0-gjshdi.5uu4vnfquqlelgdmoqysq1y3jg.cx.internal.cloudapp.net  | [B@1b29d52b  | datanode,HOST,nodemanager                                                                                                  |
| zk0-gjshdi.5uu4vnfquqlelgdmoqysq1y3jg.cx.internal.cloudapp.net  | [B@47547132  | journalnode,HOST                                                                                                           |
| zk1-gjshdi.5uu4vnfquqlelgdmoqysq1y3jg.cx.internal.cloudapp.net  | [B@655523dd  | journalnode,HOST                                                                                                           |
| zk3-gjshdi.5uu4vnfquqlelgdmoqysq1y3jg.cx.internal.cloudapp.net  | [B@6f7e336b  | journalnode,HOST                                                                                                           |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

How can I setup a query to filter on one of the UUID values ?

For example, I'd like to select just the first row from the output above but not sure about the formatting of the uuid value below. I think there's something syntactically wrong:

I've tried numerous variations and it's driving me nuts :)

```
select * from HOSTED_APPS_METADATA_UUID where UUID = [B@66e8997c;
```

...results in the following error:

```
Error: ERROR 602 (42P00): Syntax error. Missing "LPAREN" at line 1, column 47. (state=42P00,code=602)
org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixParserException: ERROR 602 (42P00): Syntax error. Missing "LPAREN" at line 1, column 47.
      at org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixParserException.newException(PhoenixParserException.java:33)
      at org.apache.phoenix.parse.SQLParser.parseStatement(SQLParser.java:111)
      at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$PhoenixStatementParser.parseStatement(PhoenixStatement.java:1644)
      at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.parseStatement(PhoenixStatement.java:1727)
      at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.execute(PhoenixStatement.java:1819)
      at sqlline.Commands.execute(Commands.java:822)
      at sqlline.Commands.sql(Commands.java:732)
      at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:813)
      at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:686)
      at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:398)
      at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:291)
Caused by: MissingTokenException(inserted [@-1,0:0='<missing LPAREN>',<100>,1:46] at UUID)
      at org.apache.phoenix.parse.PhoenixSQLParser.recoverFromMismatchedToken(PhoenixSQLParser.java:374)
      at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.org.antlr.runtime.BaseRecognizer.match(BaseRecognizer.java:115)
      at org.apache.phoenix.parse.PhoenixSQLParser.not_expression(PhoenixSQLParser.java:7851)
      at org.apache.phoenix.parse.PhoenixSQLParser.and_expression(PhoenixSQLParser.java:7671)
      at org.apache.phoenix.parse.PhoenixSQLParser.or_expression(PhoenixSQLParser.java:7608)
      at org.apache.phoenix.parse.PhoenixSQLParser.expression(PhoenixSQLParser.java:7573)
      at org.apache.phoenix.parse.PhoenixSQLParser.single_select(PhoenixSQLParser.java:5192)
      at org.apache.phoenix.parse.PhoenixSQLParser.unioned_selects(PhoenixSQLParser.java:5274)
      at org.apache.phoenix.parse.PhoenixSQLParser.select_node(PhoenixSQLParser.java:5340)
      at org.apache.phoenix.parse.PhoenixSQLParser.oneStatement(PhoenixSQLParser.java:841)
      at org.apache.phoenix.parse.PhoenixSQLParser.statement(PhoenixSQLParser.java:524)
      at org.apache.phoenix.parse.SQLParser.parseStatement(SQLParser.java:108)
      ... 9 more
```

Broader picture. I'm trying to take logging output from another application and create an isolated query in sqlline.py.

Here's an example of what this logging output looks like where the ? are replaced the values that follow:

```
SELECT UUID, SERVER_TIME, METRIC_SUM, HOSTS_COUNT, METRIC_MAX, METRIC_MIN FROM METRIC_AGGREGATE_UUID WHERE (UUID IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)) AND SERVER_TIME >= ? AND SERVER_TIME < ? ORDER BY UUID, SERVER_TIME, condition => Condition{uuids=[[B@2948f779, [B@3ca87491, [B@6702e8f, [B@7a907628, [B@148da53c, [B@6bfe57c0, [B@6cfd0866, [B@15a512e7, [B@6c78f12a, [B@75a1eb32, [B@719b73d8, [B@4c946526, [B@67ce3c3f, [B@1dcca38f, [B@3763165d], appId='NODEMANAGER', instanceId='null', startTime=1675461194000, endTime=1675461510000, limit=null, grouped=true, orderBy=[], noLimit=true}
```

Above, the base query is:

```
SELECT UUID, SERVER_TIME, METRIC_SUM, HOSTS_COUNT, METRIC_MAX, METRIC_MIN FROM METRIC_AGGREGATE_UUID WHERE (UUID IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)) AND SERVER_TIME >= ? AND SERVER_TIME < ? ORDER BY UUID, SERVER_TIME
```

and you can see the *15 UUID* parameters that follow. I can't seem to figure out how to supply a query with these uuid and I keep getting the same LPAREN error whenever I try UUID anywhere in a query.

Driver version -> PhoenixEmbeddedDriver (version 5.0)

Any tips greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Playing with this more, I'm *assuming* single quotes are needed around each UUID similar to below.  I no longer get the LPARAM error - but expected data doesn't seem to be there. Probably missing something else.

```
SELECT UUID, SERVER_TIME, METRIC_SUM, METRIC_MAX, METRIC_MIN, METRIC_COUNT FROM METRIC_RECORD_HOURLY_UUID WHERE (UUID IN ('[B@70242f38')) ORDER BY UUID, SERVER_TIME;

+-------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| UUID  | SERVER_TIME  | METRIC_SUM  | METRIC_MAX  | METRIC_MIN  | METRIC_COUNT  |
+-------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------------+
+-------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------------+
No rows selected (0.167 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked on the Phoenix User forum and received the following answer.
This explains why my queries never return any data from sqlline.py once I got past the LPARAM error using the single quotes.

> Phoenix has only added the ability to specify a binary literal in
> PHOENIX-6764, but that is not available in any released version yet.
> Currently the only way to specify binary strings in a query is via
> PreparedStatment.setBytes() in JDBC. It is not possible to specify
> them in the query text directly. Also, [B@4632cfc doesn't even look
> like a valid UUID, more like a pointer to a java object as generated
> by .toString(), so you may also have a problem with inserting.

Answer (score 0):

I used this query to find out if a certain metrics of a service been collected and saved to ams hbase and seems to work:

```
0: jdbc:phoenix:localhost:2181/ams-hbase-unse> select * from METRIC_AGGREGATE_UUID where UUID in (select UUID from METRICS_METADATA_UUID where APP_ID='datanode' and METRIC_NAME='mem_free');
+-------------+---------------+----------------------+-------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|    UUID     |  SERVER_TIME  |      METRIC_SUM      | HOSTS_COUNT |      METRIC_MAX      |      METRIC_MIN      |
+-------------+---------------+----------------------+-------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| [B@164dea80 | 1699082940000 | 1.203734E7           | 1           | 1.203734E7           | 1.203734E7           |
| [B@4392362c | 1699082970000 | 1.203734E7           | 1           | 1.203734E7           | 1.203734E7           |
| [B@338a4c61 | 1699083000000 | 1.203734E7           | 1           | 1.203734E7           | 1.203734E7           |
| [B@839755f  | 1699083030000 | 1.203734E7           | 1           | 1.203734E7           | 1.203734E7           |
| [B@71d99732 | 1699083060000 | 1.2034292E7          | 1           | 1.2034292E7          | 1.2034292E7          |
```

Comment: the UUIDs are changing for the row everytime (maybe they are memory addresses), so selecting them at the same query would show results, do not use them in query explicitly